# Using File API methods on files located in my server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, file-io

I've created a little app that browse my file system to create and display it as a tree (JTree) . Now I want to do the same for my files present on my server .
I have an Apache Tomcat server .
What I want to do is something like :

```
File dir = new File(new URI("file://localhost:8084/myapp/Dir"));

  File[] files = dir.listFiles();

    for (File f : files) {
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

this is a just an exemple but I want to use java File API .

I am getting this error when I put this code in a servlet :

`11 mai 2011 10:02:15 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet tests a généré une exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:385)`

I dont know what does this means.

I've also tried `File dir = new File("Dir") ;` and `File dir = new File("web/Dir")` and even `File dir = new File(new URI(http://localhost:8084/myapp/Dir`));

but Dir is not found . I dont get it and I am going mad (hum..sorry) .

when I type `http://localhost:8084/myapp/Dir` on my web browser the content of Dir is displayed .So Dir is really on http://localhost:8084/myapp/

I really really need some backup here .
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your webapp is deployed as an unpacked war, then you can use `getRealPath()` on the `ServletContext` object to obtain the real filesystem path for a given webapp path.

So from inside your servlet:

```
File dir = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/Dir"));
```

See [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29).

Note that this isn't good practice, and will not work on any appserver which doesn't unpack its WARs onto the filesystem before running it (e.g. Google App Engine).

Comment: Thanx for your fast answer .It works .Looks fine I will work on it .

Comment: Is there any better solution ? for Gooogle App Engine for instance .

Comment: @lemoos: Not for GAE, no, that's a very highly restricted environment.